# Enabling SSL on Visual Studio 2013 is not working

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, visual-studio-2013, https, iis-express

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. I am using Visual Studio 2013 professional version. So I tried to enable SSL in visual studio and run my project on it. But when I run it on browser, it is giving me error.

I set SSL Enabled to true in properties window:

[image]

Then I copy the SSL URL and paste changing the project URL:

[image]

When I run it on Firefox browser, it is giving me this error.

[image]

How can I fix that error?

Comment: That's desired. Self signed certificates are doomed to trigger such warnings and you should ignore them and continue.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store, as described [here](https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/18/how-to-enable-ssl-for-a-net-project-in-visual-studio/).